# jquery array .val()

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have this code below...

```
if (x == 0) {
            $("#scenariotitle").val('');
            $("#scenariosuffix").val('');
}
```

...which works fine. However, that list will grow to about 5 more jquery selects.

Is there a way to store them into an array and then use the .val('') function on all the elements in the array? If that is possible, will it be more efficient? Should I just stick to listing them out individually if the list is not greater than 10?

EDIT: I have decided to use this...

```
$("#scenariotitle, #scenariosuffix, #scenariosuffix, #scenariosuffix").val("");
```

...which is why I accepted the answer below. **However**, there is a very good discussion in the comments, and other answers provided, on how to properly use a jquery array selector.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can concat multiple selectors into one statement:

```
selector #1, selector #2, selector #3

$("#scenariotitle, #scenariosuffix, #scenariosuffix, #scenariosuffix").val("");
```

Of course you could use an array but it's quite pointless in this case:

```
var selectors = [ "selector #1", "selector #2", "selector #n" ];
for (var i=0; i<selectors.length; i++) {
    $(selectors[i]).val("");
}
```

Comment: Noooo, **never** use a `for...in` loop to iterate over an array, it's for *enumeration*.

Comment: @Nick Craver: It's *for* what ever purpose it is used for.

Comment: @Orbling - No, it's not, ` for( in )` is for *enumeration*, a traditional `for()` loop is for *iteration*, there are differences, please don't confuse the two.

Comment: @Nick Craver: *Enumeration* is just a special case of *iteration*.

Comment: @Orbling - No, it's not.  You're off base with that claim, they produce different results.  For example in IE, you'll iterate the array indexes **in the other they were added**, not **the order of the array**.  You shouldn't use a `for(...in...)` on an array...you'll get both an unexpected order in some cases, as well as **items not in the array**, how can you say this is correct usage?  If you don't believe me, try this in various browsers, including IE: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/HLB5v/

Comment: @Nick Craver: Because order is not always important and if you have a pure array, not an object in disguise, there will be no additional properties, just the elements.  In this case, order is utterly unimportant and the array is created directly overhead - the usage reads more clearly for the use "for all selectors" rather than "for i = 0 to selectors.length".

Comment: @Orbling: @Nick is right. In javascript, an Array *is* an object in disguise. This practice does lead to broken code, and shouldn't be promoted. It may be fine in some languages. In javascript it isn't.

Comment: @Orbling - "there will be no additional properties"....I just gave you a link to a demo showing that there will be, proving it...I'm not sure how you're making that claim.  You're promoting a *very* bad practice with undesired results and side-effects, **why?**  Why not do it the right way?

Comment: Thanks Nick. I am going to use the multiple jquery selection. Never realized I can do that, I am quite new to jquery. Also, if I ever need to create an array, now I know how to work with them.

Comment: I don't normally edit others' answers, but in this case since it was accepted I felt it best - it should be a good example to others finding it later.

Comment: @Nick Craver: In your example, you deliberately sabotaged the Array class by adding a property to the prototype.  Granted, you can get in to hot water with it.  When it works, it works; when it does not, do not use it.

Comment: @Orbling - Or do it the right way and eliminate any possibility of errors. Deliberately?  Yes, and *many* libraries extend the Array prototype - the only difference in my example is you had the luxury of seeing the code right there, and not a library elsewhere doing it.  I don't understand your aversion to *doing it the right way*, I'm actually baffled by it.

Comment: @Orbling http://prototypejs.org/ - Never heard of that? Then don't comment on JavaScript things.

Comment: @Nick Craver: I have no aversion to a regular `for` loop.  I am just saying there are instances where the other approach works, when there are no modifications to the base class.  Also, I am in the camp that thinks editing for anything other than formatting is always wrong.  I certainly did not mean this to end up in a lengthy preaching session.

Comment: @Orbling - "there are instances where the other approach works"...yes, there are, but not in an assured order and only if assumptions about the prototype are correct - it's still a bad practice.  For the editing: I *very* rarely edit another answer, maybe 4 or 5 times ever, but in this case an accepted answer was blatantly wrong...and SO is a resource for others looking for help later...they deserve to get that help, not problematic code and practices.

Comment: @Nick Craver: I think the comments would definitely have set them straight. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You can store the selectors in an array, then combine them for use if you wanted, like this:

```
var selectors = ["#scenariotitle", "#scenariosuffix"];
$(selectors.join(", ")).val("");
```

This takes the array then using [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) turns it into a [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) (comma separated) to grab all the elements at once.

Answer (score 2):

Crozin has already mentioned a good way to reset based on the IDs so I won't repeat his solution. Another option that you can consider would be using a class selector.

If your HTML looked like this:

```
<input type='text' name='scenariotitle' class='resettable' />
<input type='text' name='scenariosuffix' class='resettable' />
<input type='text' name='scenariosomething' class='resettable' />
<input type='text' name='scenarioagain' class='resettable' />
```

Then you can have this:

```
$(".resettable").val("");
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding an extra case to what Crozin wrote (which is all correct).  If you need to accrue the list over time, just add them to a jQuery object.

```
var blankList = $();

...

blankList = blankList.add('#scenarioTitle');
...
blankList = blankList.add('#scenarioSuffix, #secondSuffix');
...

if (x == 0) {
    blankList.val('');
}
```

Comment: This will not have the desired effect, `.add()` doesn't change the collection, it *returns* a new collection with the items added.  In your code above, `blankList` would have `0` elements at all steps.

Comment: This will work fine if you just overwrite the old value of `blankList` each time, as in: `blankList = blankList.add('#scenarioTitle');`

Comment: @Nick Craver: Good point, an omission error I make a lot.  Corrected.

Comment: +1 Nice solution if not all the elements are available immediately. Avoids reselecting them.

Comment: @patricy dw: It's quite visually clean like this in that case, though I think Nick's solution adapted to be multi-stage (building an array of selectors) may be more efficient, it depends on the overhead sizzle has with the `,` separator versus the overhead of adding to an existing jQuery object.